# react app yarn test fails with exit code 1, while yarn start works

Tags: reactjs

I've just been using npm for the most part when working with my react app first time using yarn as it's needed for a project. ran yarn start and the app works fine. but when i do yarn test. it fails and I have to pass that test to upload the assignment...

```
PS C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\blogpaginationproject\b5f23d> yarn test
yarn run v1.22.18
$ react-scripts test
Error: Failed to initialize watch plugin "node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/filename.js":

● Test suite failed to run

file:///C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/blogpaginationproject/b5f23d/node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/build/file_name_plugin/prompt.js:4
import { PatternPrompt, printPatternCaret, printRestoredPatternCaret } from 'jest-watcher';
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'printPatternCaret' not found. The requested module 'jest-watcher' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'jest-watcher';
const { PatternPrompt, printPatternCaret, printRestoredPatternCaret } = pkg;

  at async requireOrImportModule (node_modules/jest-util/build/requireOrImportModule.js:65:32)
  at async watch (node_modules/@jest/core/build/watch.js:337:34)
  at async _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:311:7)
  at async runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Complete noob at this, I don't even know where to start trouble shooting this "problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11792#issuecomment-998851765

Looks like there is an issue with node version (`jest-watch` package which is used by `react-scripts` only works in certain node versions)

- Major version 14 and minimum minor version 17 (^14.17.0)
- Major version 16 (>=16.0.0)

You can check your node version by typing: `node -v` in your terminal.
To change your node version you can use a node manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is indeed one of the many problems i currently have